# Is there any way to populate the database without having to add the values ​manually? Python/MySQL/Excel

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I need to put data from a spreadsheet into a MySQL DB. I created the following code but it doesn't work. I've tried it in several ways and none have worked.

Is there any way to populate the database without having to add the values ​​manually?

The following error always appears

Error: "not enough arguments for format string"

```
if os.path.isfile('Desafio.csv'):

        try:
                csv = pd.read_csv("Desafio.csv", skiprows = range(0, 14))
                for row in csv:
                    con = pymysql.connect(db='new_schema', user='root', passwd='password123H.')
                    cursor = con.cursor()
                    query = "INSERT INTO afastamentos(codigo,custo,identificacao,funcionario,cargo,data_do_afastamento,especialidade,motivo,funcionario_lider) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
                    cursor.execute(query,row)               
                    con.commit()
                    print('Dados inseridos com sucesso!')
                    cursor.close()
                    con.close()
        except Exception as erro:
                    print('Erro!', erro)
```

Comment: Why not import the `csv` file as it is to a new table in the database then use `INSERT` query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are getting for `row` when you do `for row in csv:` is column names one by one. You aren't getting a row of data.

Try:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows(): # this gives index and row, we won't use the index
    row = [x for x in row] # turns the row into a list instead of a pd.Series, made up of the elements within it
    ... # make cursor and connection and all that
    ...
    cursor.execute(query,row)
```

I'd also recommend taking advantage of the context-closing/committing with the cursor.

```py
with pymysql.connect(db='new_schema', user='root', passwd='password123H.') as con
    with con.cursor() as cursor:
        for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
            row = [x for x in row] 
            ... # make cursor and connection and all that
            ...
            cursor.execute(query,row)
            con.commit()
```

When it leaves the `with` blocks, it'll automatically call `.close()` as approriate.

Comment: for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row = [x for x in row]
    con = pymysql.connect(db='new_schema', user='root', passwd='pass')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO afasta(codigo,custo,identificacao,funcionario,cargo,data_do_afastamento,especialidade,motivo,funcionario_lider) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
    cursor.execute(query,row)               
    con.commit()
    print('Dados inseridos com sucesso!')
    cursor.close()
    con.close()

And now i get the error (1265, "Data truncated for column 'custo' at row 1")
My csv file begin in the line 13

Comment: I tried the first option and now i get the error (1265, "Data truncated for column 'custo' at row 1") My csv file begin in the line 13

Comment: first thought on that is that the value for column `custo` in row 1 doesn't fit into where you are trying to put it. What is the datatype for the column in the database and what is it trying to insert into the database? use a debugger with your IDE to set a breakpoint at the `cursor.execute()` line and see what the value of the `row` variable is. is it what you expect?